# How to connect a specific Bluetooth device using Google Assistant?

Tags: bluetooth, google-assistant

I wanted to know if there was a command for Google Assistant to connect a specific Bluetooth device.
It would be very convenient to use in the car so you don't waste time fiddling with your cell phone.

Comment: Example: "OK Google, connect to Pixel Buds Pro."